# UITableViewCell not clipping to bounds during expand animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to implement a fairly simple table view with an expanding cell containing a UIDatePicker, with autolayout/Masonry and automatically sized cells.

I'm having a problem with the date picker cell expanding in a nice way. When the cell containing the date picker begins to expand, its contents appear outside of the cell, even though I have `clipsToBounds = YES` on both the cell itself and cell.contentView. I've also tried re-setting `clipsToBounds = YES` after `layoutSubviews`.

Sorry about the quality, but here's a gif showing the animation problem in slow motion.

[image: Animation Glitch]

Any ideas on how I can keep the date picker clipped inside its cell? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Possibly Relevant Code Snippets:

Insert/Remove

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];

if (showingStartTimePicker) {
    [sections[TableSectionTimes] insertObject:@(TableRowStartTimePicker) atIndex:index];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:TableSectionTimes]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
} else {
    [sections[TableSectionTimes] removeObject:@(TableRowStartTimePicker)];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:TableSectionTimes]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
}

[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

DatePickerCell

```
- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {

        [self setClipsToBounds:YES];
        [self.contentView setClipsToBounds:YES];

        _picker = [UIDatePicker new];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_picker];
        [_picker makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.edges.equalTo(self.contentView);
        }];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: do u use xib for the tablecell ? IF yes, set the clipsToBound to YES in the awakeFromNib method.

Comment: No, it's entirely programmatic

Comment: There is an example here that you may glean some information from - it's Swift, but the concepts will be the same: http://www.appcoda.com/expandable-table-view/  --- Alternatively, I have a GitHub repo that demonstrates a couple ways to show/hide cell elements - again in Swift, but concepts yada yada: https://github.com/DonMag/DynamicCellHeight

Comment: The relevant example there adds the picker to the same cell as the "Start time" label, starting to look like I may have to just do that instead of inserting a new row just for the picker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I ended up going with was changing `UITableViewRowAnimationTop` to `UITableViewRowAnimationFade` so that the row is mostly invisible during the portions of the animation where it's showing through.